# How to get roots in the form of a quadratic from the quartic $x^4 - 4x^2 + 16$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots, factoring, quartics

So I need to factor this function into quadratics:

$$x^4 - 4x^2 + 16$$

I know that there are only complex solutions to this question, however, it is still possible to obtain quadratic factors without requiring the imaginary unit to be present.

I tried by simplifying it into a quadratic by replacing $x^2 =a$.

But I just end up getting (after completing the square) $$(x^2-2)^2+12$$

which is not in factored format. So could someone help me?

Comment: "*but I just end up getting $(x^2-2)^2+12$.*"  Why?  Factor $a^2-4a+16$ into the form $(a-c_1)(a-c_2)$ instead... not as $(a-v)^2+b$.  Factor in order to get the roots, not completing the square to find the vertex.

Comment: Are those supposed to be complex solutions, because I have not learnt how to factor into complex yet

Comment: Recall your quadratic formula.  $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ factors as $\left(x-\dfrac{-B+\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}\right)\left(x-\dfrac{-B-\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}\right)$.

Comment: As for getting *real* roots of $(x^2-2)^2+12$, notice that $(x^2-2)^2$ is a square and so is always non-negative given real values of $x$ and $12$ is positive so $(x^2-2)^2+12$ is always greater than or equal to $12$... and in particular never equals zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz I get a complex solution if I use the quadratic formula

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We see that, the roots of the equation are not real numbers.  So, if we want to factor polynomials whose coefficients are real numbers, and if that's possible, then we have

$$\begin{align}x^4-4x^2+16=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b) \end{align} \tag 1$$

This factorization uses the following fact:

If $x_1,x_2$ are the root of the biquadratic, then $-x_1,-x_2$ are also roots of the biquadratic. So, you have

$$\begin{align}x^4-4x^2+16&=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b)\\
&=(x^2+b)^2-a^2x^2\\
&=x^4+x^2(2b-a^2)+b^2 \end{align}$$

This implies,

$$\begin{align}\begin{cases}2b-a^2=-4\\b^2=16\end{cases}&\implies a^2=12,\thinspace b=4\\
&\implies a=±2\sqrt 3,\thinspace b=4.\end{align}$$

---

**Explanation:** $~(1)$

Since the roots of the polynomial are not real numbers, it is not possible to factor the coefficients with real numbers such that

$$x^4-4x^2+16=(x-a)(x^3+bx^2+cx+d)$$

That is, the polynomial $x^4-4x^2+16$ will be factored with real coefficients as follows:

$$x^4-4x^2+16=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+mx+n)$$

Then, let $x_1, \thinspace x_2$ are the root of the polynomial $x^2+ax+b$. So, the roots of the second multiplier polynomial must be $-x_1,\thinspace -x_2$. Based on the [Vieta's formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) we immediately obtain the coefficients of the second multiplier polynomial as follows:

$$\begin{align}m&=-\left(-x_1+(-x_2)\right)\\
&=x_1+x_2\\
&=-a\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}n&=-x_1\times (-x_2)\\
&=x_1x_2\\
&=b\end{align}$$

Thus, our polynomial will be factored as

$$\begin{align}x^4-4x^2+16=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b).\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice explanation $(+1)$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig When you see errors like this, I'd be honored if you edited the answer.  Even if it's a typo, it might confuse the OP. I fixed. Thank you for reviewing my answer.

Comment: @Soheil Thank you for reviewing my answer. 
   $\\$      (◜‿◝ )

Comment: I also think you wrote a very nice explanation.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It's real honor to hear from a mathematician for a small job.  Many thanks again. ( ◜‿◝ ) (excuse me for grammatical errors).

Comment: Very nice explanation! I have given your answer a green tick. I just want to ask whether this method is applicable for all quartics with even powers and only complex solutions

Comment: @ShootingStars Thanks. The quartic with only even degree is just the polynomial $ax^4+bx^2+c$. The general factorization with real coefficients for quartics with complex roots is as follows: $$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=a(x^2+mx+n)(x^2+px+q)$$

Comment: @lonestudent Ok, thanks!

Comment: +1 Nice answer. There is one step that seems incomplete though; you state that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the roots of one quadratic factor, then $-x_1$ and $-x_2$ must be the roots of the other quadratic factor, and so $m=-a$ and $n=b$. The implied argument seems to be that if $x_i$ is a root of the biquadratic, then so is $-x_i$. But what if $x_2=-x_1$?

Comment: @Servaes Thank you very much!..I'm actually trying to understand your comment exactly.  I read your comment, but I may still have misunderstood.Let me say this: In this case the roots of the first polynomial are $x_1,-x_1$ and the roots of the second olynomial are $-x_1,x_1$.This means, we have $(x^2+b)^2$. But, $x^4-4x^2+16≠(x^2+b)^2$.Because, $a≠0$. But, if what you want to say is the sign of $a$,then the polynomials just swap places.For example, if we make $a\mapsto -a$, then we can see that the polynomial product does not change.So, the argument works.Sorry if I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @lonestudent Thanks for your reply. In this case, why are the roots of the second polynomial $-x_1$, $x_1$? Why not $x_2$, $-x_2$? In the end it still works out, as then the product becomes 
$$x^4-4x^2+16=(x^2+b)(x^2+n),$$
 which does not lead to a solution. But you seem to overlook this case.

Comment: Alternatively, you can circumvent this case by noting that the roots of the biquadratic come in (nonzero) pairs $\pm x_1$ and $\pm x_2$, and continue as you did.

Comment: Great answer! 

Answer (score 3):

The polynomial $f=x^4-4x^2+16$ cannot be factored over $\Bbb Q$, since it is irreducible. Over the real numbers it factorizes into
$$
f=\left(x^2 + xa + \frac{a^2 - 4}{2}\right)\left(x^2 - xa + \frac{a^2 - 4}{2}\right)
$$
with $a=2\sqrt{3}$. One can see this by writing it as $$(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$$
and compare coefficients.

Comment: If $x_1,x_2$ are the roots, then $-x_1,-x_2$ are also roots. I think, this immediately implies, $$...=(x^2-ax+b)(x^2+ax+b)$$

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, sure. But it is the same as $a+c=0$, which anyway follows immediately from the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$x^4-4x^2+16=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+b)$$
which gives the equations $b^2=16,2b-a^2=-4$. This solves to $b=4,a=\sqrt{12}$, so
$$x^4-4x^2+16=(x^2+\sqrt{12}x+4)(x^2-\sqrt{12}x+4)$$

Comment: How did you know precisely that the factors were going to be $x^2 + AX+B$ and $x^2 -AX+B$? they could have been different values as well

Comment: @ShootingStars Standard trick. If you assume one factor _of a biquadratic_ is $x^2+ax+b$ you can work out that the other factor must be $x^2-ax+b$ by comparing the $x^3$ and $x^1$ coefficients. The Galois group is in general $C_2^2$.

Answer (score 0):

${x}^{\mathrm{4}} −\mathrm{4}{x}^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{16} \\ $
${x}^{\mathrm{4}} +\mathrm{8}{x}^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{16}\:−\mathrm{12}{x}^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $
$\left({x}+\mathrm{4}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} −\mathrm{12}{x}^{\mathrm{2}}  \\ $
$\left({x}+\mathrm{4}+\sqrt{\mathrm{12}}{x}\right)\left({x}+\mathrm{4}−\sqrt{\mathrm{12}}{x}\right) \\ $
$\left(\left(\mathrm{1}+\mathrm{2}\sqrt{\mathrm{3}}\right){x}+\mathrm{4}\right)\left(\left(\mathrm{1}−\mathrm{2}\sqrt{\mathrm{3}}\right){x}+\mathrm{4}\right) \\ $

Answer (score 0):

(a little theory to lead into where you left off )

Since the quartic polynomial $ \ z^4 - 4z^2 + 16 \ $ has real coefficients, we know that its zeroes form two complex-conjugate pairs (since $ \ (-4)^2 - 4·1·16 \ < \ 0 \ ) $ .  So its factorization is
$$ ( z - \alpha - i \beta)·( z - \alpha + i \beta)·( z - \gamma - i \delta)·( z - \gamma + i \delta) $$ $$ = \ \ ( \ z^2 - 2·\alpha·z + [\alpha^2 + \beta^2] \ )·( \ z^2 - 2·\gamma·z + [\gamma^2 + \delta^2] \ ) \ \ . $$

But this polynomial is also biquadratic, and therefore is an even function.  Since there are no terms with odd powers of $ \ x \ \ , $ we must have
$$ -2·(\alpha + \gamma)·z^3 \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \gamma \ = \ -\alpha  \ \ , $$
$$ -2·( \ \alpha·[\gamma^2 + \delta^2] \ + \ \gamma·[\alpha^2 + \beta^2] \ )·z \ \ = \ \ 0 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \alpha·[\alpha^2 + \delta^2] \ - \ \alpha·[\alpha^2 + \beta^2]   \ \ = \ \ 0  \ \  \Rightarrow \ \   \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ \gamma^2 \ \ . $$

We find then that the four complex zeroes are the vertices of a rectangle in the Argand diagram as $ \ z \ = \ \pm \alpha \ \pm \ i·\beta \ \ . $  (This is consistent with the expectation that the sum of the zeroes is zero and the sum of the reciprocals of the zeroes is $ \ -\frac{0}{16} \ \ . ) \ $  This makes the factorization
$$ \ ( \ z^2 - 2·\alpha·z + [\alpha^2 + \beta^2] \ )·( \ z^2 + 2·\alpha·z + [\alpha^2 + \beta^2] \ ) $$ $$ = \ \ z^4 \ - \ 2·( \ [\alpha^2 + \beta^2] - 2·\alpha^2 \ )·z^2 \ + \ [\alpha^2 + \beta^2]^2 $$
$$ = \ \ z^4 \ - \ 2·( \alpha^2 - \beta^2)·z^2 \ + \ [\alpha^2 + \beta^2]^2  \ \ . \quad \quad \mathbf{[1]} $$

(If this seems a bit reminiscent of "the difference-of-two-squares", you wouldn't be far off...)

Now, your "completion-of-the-square" is $ \ z^4 - 4z^2 + 16 \ = \ (z^2 - 2)^2 \ + \ 12 \ \ . $ If we complete-the-square for equation $ \ \mathbf{1} \ $ , we have
$$   [ \ z^2 \ - \  ( \alpha^2 - \beta^2) \ ]^2  \ + \ (\alpha^2 + \beta^2)^2 \ - \ ( \alpha^2 - \beta^2)^2 \ \ = \ \ [ \ z^2 \ - \  ( \alpha^2 - \beta^2) \ ]^2  \ + \ 4·\alpha^2 · \beta^2  \ \  . \ \ \mathbf{[2]} $$

By comparing  corresponding terms in equations $ \ \mathbf{1} \ $ and $ \ \mathbf{2} \ $, we find
$$   ( \alpha^2 + \beta^2 )^2 \ \ = \ \ 16 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \alpha^2 + \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ 4 \ \ \ , \ \ \ \alpha^2 - \beta^2 \  =  \ 2 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \   \alpha^2 \ \ = \ \ 3 \ \ \ , \ \ \ \beta^2 \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ $$
(this is consistent with $  \ 4·\alpha^2 · \beta^2  \ = \ 12 \ ) \ . $

Thus we obtain the factorization
$$ z^4 \ - \ 4z^2 \ + \ 16 \ \ = \ \ ( \ z^2 \ - \ 2 \sqrt3·z \ +  \ 4 \ ) \ · \ ( \ z^2 \ +  \ 2 \sqrt3·z \ +  \ 4 \ ) $$
with the zeroes of the polynomial being $ \ z \ = \ \pm \sqrt3 \ \pm \ i \ \ . $

[Since it is asked about in the comments elsewhere, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277844/s-p-are-sum-and-product-of-real-roots-of-x4-7x2-5-0-what-is-the-value/4416816#4416816) is a problem where the biquadratic polynomial has two real and two complex (in fact, purely imaginary) zeroes.]